# Why is everything a pointer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop

I come from a PHP/Javascript background where things are stored in a variable directly in most cases, where we also had Object/Classes/Methods, etc. It was OOP.

Now I'm starting to learn Objective-C. I understand the basics of pointers. But everything is a pointer now. This is the part that I don't get. Why aren't we like in PHP/Javascript with direct assignment? We are still doing OOP afterall.

Thanks

Comment: What does your definition of OOP have to do with languages that are "safe" and languages that are "unsafe?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the semantics of JavaScript and many other OO languages (perhaps including PHP, but I'm not sure and not willing to guess), you'll see that these languages offer the same indirection Objective C offers through pointers. In fact, internally these languages use pointers everywhere. Consider this (JavaScript) snippet:

```
function f(obj) {
    obj.x = 1; // modifies the object referred to directly
    obj = {x: 2}; // doesn't affect caller
}
var foo = {x: 0};
f(foo); // passes a pointer/"reference"
// foo.x === 1
```

It's roughly equivalent to (C as I don't know Objective C) something like this, modulo manual memory management, static typing, etc.:

```
struct Obj { int x; };
void f(struct Obj *obj) {
    obj->x = 1;
    obj = ...; // you get the idea
}
struct Obj *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
foo->x = 0;
f(foo);
free(foo);
```

It's just explicit in Objective C because that language's a superset of C (100% backwards compability and interoperability), while other languages have done away with explicit pointers and made the indirection they need implicit.

Comment: "based on" is a little vague. I often read it as "a strict superset" of C, which is probably more accurate.

Comment: So you are saying here...f(foo) in your javascript section. We are really passing a pointer to the foo object into the function?

Comment: @WilliamSham: Well, it's not quite as versatile as a pointer in C (and thus Objective C), thus the alternative term "reference". But basically, yes. The object is not copied, only a symbolic token (pointer, reference, address, call it what you want) that allows modifying the object directly.

Comment: @delnan, Thanks. And how do you explain this concept of it is really just "pointers" in play, with reference to Ryan Wersal's comment about actually "passing by value" and variable get copied.

Comment: Well, these pointers as passed by value (as the `obj = ...` lines in my examples illustrate, chaning the pointer has no effect on the caller). But some argue that that already qualifies as pass-by-reference as it allows modifying the object (I disagree, but it's important to realize this concept is known under many names). Pass-by-value and -reference are concepts, while pointers are just tools. Usually pass-by-reference is done in C by passing a pointer *to a variable*. But in JS there's no such thing, *everything* is a pointer to an object.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you also work only with pointers but transparently. 
Really you using references to objects

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the designers of Objective-C decided to go with using pointers on everything that is an Objective-C object include the following:

1. So they can deal with behind the scenes memory management without taking away the programmers ability to do so on his own.
2. Fast Enumeration on objects.
3. (Perhaps the most important) Gives the ability to have id types that can pass nil(null) values without crashing the program.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the other answers here: in PHP and other languages you are still using pointers. That is why there is still a distinction between [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and passing by value. There are several good sites that help [explain the distinction](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/php/pass_by_reference.html), both in syntax and what it means to pass by either method.

---

**Edit:**
Refer to the second link in my post. My interpretation of that information is that PHP passes by *value* by default. Adding the ampersand in front of the variable during the function call passes a *reference* (or rather the address of the variable). In essence, passing by reference is passing a pointer while passing by value does a copy of the value completely. They also have different implications on their usage (reference allows modifying the original variable's value, even outside the scope of the function etc).

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. But like some other comments here, which say PHP actually only work with pointers, they just made the referencing implicit. Does that mean when I "pass by value", it's actually still a passing by "pointer" in disguise?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your questions. To more directly answer your "pointer" in disguise: no. If pass by value is default, then you are copying the value when you pass it to a function. The implicit nature of these languages is such that you are using pointers throughout your code without you needing to be concerned with it (at least to the degree of Obj-C, C, C++, etc).

Comment: Another way of thing of it is to say "passing by reference by value" this is because the reference (pointer) to the object is being copied.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C is a strict superset and extension of ANSI C, so the native types that could be compatibly added to the language were constrained (perhaps by the original implementation).  But this compatibility with ANSI C has turned out to be one of the advantages of using Objective C mixed with the reuse of cross-platform C code.

BTW, OOP and "safety" are nearly orthogonal concepts.  They each have different potential costs in terms of consuming CPU cycles and/or eating the user's battery power.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are created using the `+alloc` method, which allocates space for the new object on the heap. In C, and therefore in Objective-C, the only way to refer to memory on the heap is through a pointer.